# How to de normalize text saved in a text area with HTML tags

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have an object that I've entered text with HTML snippets that I want to insert into a page using JavaScript. When the string is passed in the object(s) using Apex, the strings are normalized so that the `<` character is replaced with `&lt;` and the `>` character is replaced with `&gt;`. I'd like to covert them back and add them using the element.innerHTML property but I'm having issues translating the `&lt;` back to a `<`.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I ended up overcoming the problem by changing so that I store my marked up text with [b] for <b>. Then after the object is translated from Apex to Ajax, I found that this is where the data was being normalized, I replace the [b] tag with <b> and it works fine. I'll just have to add support for some other tags. Global replace of the brackets might cause problems if the user likes them in their text.

Comment: I couldn't seem to make any of the suggestions work. The problem is in the translation from what is stored to the Ajax message that is sent to the web page. I changed so that using a [b][/b] for storing the script then translating the [b][/b] pair to <b></b> when the handler renders the innerHTML for an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot make it in Apex, you can try doing it in JavaScript instead:

```
function unescapeHtml(escapedString) {
    return escapedString
        .replace(/&amp;/g, "&")
        .replace(/&lt;/g, "<")
        .replace(/&gt;/g, ">")
        .replace(/&quot;/g, "\"")
        .replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
}
```

Comment: I'd been trying to do .replace( "&amp;", "&" ) but for some reason, it doesn't find the string "&apm;". I'd not thought of using an expression. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `unescapeHtml4` method of the [String object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm).
Here is an example from the doc:

```
String s1 = '&quot;&lt;Black&amp;White&gt;&quot;';
String s2 = s1.unescapeHtml4();
System.assertEquals('"<Black&White>"',s2);
```

On the visualforce page you can use `escape="false"` parameter of the `apex:outputText`.

Comment: The problem is that I am sending an array of the Apex class in the Ajax return. Once it gets to the client side, I can't use that method in the JavaScript.

Comment: It looks like it is in the translation from the Apex object to the JavaScript object. The underlying Ajax handler must be normalizing the strings when they are passed to the browser.

Comment: Just as mast0r said, use escape="false" in Visualforce. Also, you need to render this text in a VF component such as apex:outputText for it to remain in the original format (including escape=false).